# Parse a json with only integar values in C#

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I am trying to parse a json and populate these values into an object with DataContractJsonSerializer. Having no luck with this yet.

The json is -

```
{
"0": [
    547,
    541,
    507,
    548,
    519,
    0
],
"1": [
    573,
    504
]
}
```

I have tried the following code:

```
  try
        {
            string json = @"""0"":[547,541,507,548,519,0],""1"":[573,504]";
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                var seraializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
                var jsonParsed = seraializer.ReadObject(memStream);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Always getting an exception that the data is invalid at the root. But online json validators say this is a valid json.

MyClass -

```
  [DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> values { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks Patrick for providing me a working solution with Newtonsoft.  But just to learn , I want to see what am I doing wrong with DataContractJsonSerializer. The code below gives me no exception, but I am not getting any values after the parsing is complete.

```
 string json = @"{""0"":[547,541,507,548,519,0],""1"":[573,504]}";
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                var seraializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, List<int>>));
                var jsonParsed = seraializer.ReadObject(memStream);
            }
```

Comment: Please add your parser. Otherwise we can't tell you where you did something wrong.

Comment: what @Thomas said plus, what is wrong? Some exception? Some data is missing?

Comment: There is some parts we would need to see as already pointed out. If you are not sure what would be important to post, see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some examples.

Comment: What does MyClass look like?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added MyClass eariler only.

Comment: Aren't you missing the opening `{` and closing `}` in your `json` string in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` as the type to deserialize to. You also need to use the right serializer (`DataContractSerializer` is for XML, `DataContractJsonSerializer` for JSON):

```
var seraializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, List<int>>), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings() { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true });
var jsonParsed = seraializer.ReadObject(memStream);
```

Or for JSON.NET:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>(json);
```

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? It works for the code provided by OP. I tested both solutions.

Comment: @patrick Yes those suggestions are really correct. But now, Im not getting any exceptions but, there are no values after deserialization.

Comment: Can you give it a retry? @sant

Comment: Also, your string in your code is different from the JSON you gave use.

Comment: string json = @"{""0"":[547,541,507,548,519,0],""1"":[573,504]}"; I updated the string to this value

Comment: Yes I added  {} after you guys suggested.Works perfectly with Newtonsoft. Thanks for that. But datacontractjsonserialzer still is not giving values.         -- This is code I'm using now. Anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Yes, you didn't listen when I asked you to check the updated code.